# Linq LIKE functionality

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, like-keyword

so.. I'm using LinqToEntities, and I want to query part of a field.  Normally I'd use the LIKE keyword with SQL, and then go from there..

I see that Linq does not have it.. Whats a good way to get the same kind of functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`String.StartsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) or [`String.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx).

For example:

```
var query = from b in db.Books
            where b.Title.Contains("time")
            select b;
```

This works because LINQ turns the query into an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), and for LINQ to SQL/Entities, many "standard" C# methods are supported for the conversion to SQL.